# How do I scan for a "string" constant in a flex scanner?

Tags: regex, string, flex-lexer

As part of a class assignment to create a flex scanner, I need to create a rule that recognizes a string constant. That is, a collection of characters between a set of quotation marks. How do I identify a bad string?

Comment: Not the typical comment you see on a question like this, but what have you tried?

Comment: Help use help you! At the very least: show your efforts, include example inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 0):

The only way a string literal can be "bad" is if it is missing the closing quote mark. Unfortunately, that is not easy to detect, since it is likely that there is another string literal in the program, and the opening quote of the following string literal will be taken as the missing close quote. Once the quote marks are out of synch, the lexical scan will continue incorrectly until the end of file is detected inside a supposed string literal, at which point an error can be reported.

Languages like the C family do not allow string literals to contain newline characters, which allows missing quotes to be detected earlier. In that case, a "bad" string literal is one which contains a newline. It's quite possible that the lexical scan will incorrectly include characters which were intended to be outside of the string literal, but error recovery is somewhat easier than in languages in which a missing quote effectively inverts the entire program.

It's worth noting that it is almost as common to accidentally fail to *escape* a quote inside a quoted string, which will result in the string literal being closed prematurely; the intended close quote will then be lexed as an open quote, and the eventual lexical error will again be delayed.

(F)lex uses the "longest match" rule to identify which pattern to recognize. If the string pattern doesn't allow newlines, as in C, it might be (in a simplified version, leaving out the complication of escapes) something like:

```
\"[^"]*\"
```

(remembering that in flex, `.` does not match a newline.) If the closing quote is not present in the line, this pattern will not match, and it is likely that the fallback pattern will succeed, matching only the open quote. That's good enough if immediate failure is acceptable, but if you want to do error recovery, you probably want to ignore the rest of the line. In that case, you might add a pattern such as

```
\"[^"]*
```

That will match every valid string as well, of course (not including the closing quote) but it doesn't matter because the valid string literal pattern's match will be longer (by one character). So the pattern without the closing quote will only match unterminated string literals.